# Create database table with current date as tablename

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a database table with current date as tablename using sql query

Comment: Probably the worst architectural decision I've heard in a looong time. Why would you want to do this??

Comment: As said if you find yourself having a bunch of tables named for a specific *entity* - be it date, company name, user - there is almost always a better way of doing things (i.e. a single table with date column)

Comment: I don't think either of the DBMSs you specified support slashes in a table name.

Comment: You could use insert into.

Comment: Why do you have c# and two separate database servers tagged?

Comment: If anything, I would use TableNameYYYYMMDD.  So it could be Customers20141029.  I would not put any special characters or spaces in table names.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server or MySQL (one is made by microsoft and the other is oracle and they are very different).

Comment: @walther I want to save particular files uploaded in a particular date in database....  so i decided to create a table with the date as tabelname.. If any1 has better options then please suggest...

Comment: @JNevill SQL Server...

Comment: Thanx @RajMore But i want to dynamically create a database table and i  have slashes in the format of date so can u suggest how to create it??

Comment: You should seriously learn about some SQL design practices. One file should be a row, but one day shouldn't be a whole table. I can't provide any real answer with this description of your "problem", but easiest way would be just another column "date" and that's it. Finished work. It's insane to have a table for each day.

Comment: @walther.. I have the requirement of this, that's why i want to do it like this and it's not insane plz... If you have a suggestion than please tell..

Comment: @AlexK. actually i have a bunch of files being uploaded at particular date so i want to save them in database according to the dates..
that's why i want to create a table with particular date so that i can save them according to dates and whenever i need them again i'll fetch them by calling different dates table.. Please help if you can..

Comment: `select * from all_uploads where date=@date` is hugely superior to the alternative

Comment: @AlexK. Thanx for the reply.. I have done it directly with SQL Server.. I created 26/10/2014 tablename directly.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can name a table basically anything you want by enclosing it in [].

So generate dynamic sql and execute it:

```
EXEC sp_executesql  N'create table [12/10/2014] (ab varchar(10));'
```

Further you can get the whole thing dynamically:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'create table [' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 101) + '] (ab varchar(10))'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

EDIT: This was originally tagged as MySQL so here is the solution for that as well, because I was curious.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y');
SET @SQL =CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `' ,DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y'), '` (id int(10))');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I think it's not a good option, You can get the current date from C# using

```
DateTime.Today
```

It can look like

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        try
        {               
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + "someNamingPrefixHere_" + DateTime.Today + " (ab varchar(10));", con))
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply.. 
I created it directly with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

### first:

do you really need to create a table that has a name as current date? why not create only a table and add a field that is a date and keep adding your data filling the date field with the current date?

### if you really need to create many tables then:

you can't have a table name with the "/" character, you will have to replace those with something that is accepted by MySQL or SQLServer.

anyway to get the current date in c# use the [DateTime.Now Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) in c# and then you can format it using the [DateTime.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) passing the format you wish to use like:

```
string tableName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

this will give you a result like "29102014" if it's 29th october 2014.

then you can create the sql statement using the sql syntax from MySQL or SQLServer, open a connection, execute the command and then close the connection.

Comment: check the error code that you are recieving, maybe it's a permission error that your database user doesn't have the rights to create a table. anyway you have to post the code so we can see

Comment: also are you really using c#? or is this just inside SQLServer? i'm asking because the tags have been removed

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously learn about some SQL design practices. One file should be a row, but one day shouldn't be a whole table. I can't provide any specific answer with this description of your "problem", but easiest way would be just add another column "date" and that's it. Finished work. It's insane to have a table for each day.

Comment: I have the requirement of this, that's why i want to do it like this and it's not insane plz... If you have a suggestion than please tell..

Comment: @HimanshuBisht, requirement from WHO? Someone who never designed a sql table structure? Sounds like a nonsense school assignment.

Comment: Now I have created the table with name 26/10/2014 directly by SQL Server 2012. So please if u don't know how to make it doesn't mean it can't happen..
Don't blame others before trying it yourself.. :) :P

Comment: @HimanshuBisht, where/when did I say it's impossible??? All I'm saying is that it's a nonsense practice that should never be used in a real life scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I obtained a table name with date and time like `MY_TABLE_2019-03-25_08h45m32s687` in MS SQL server:

```
DECLARE @MIGRATION_TABLE_1 VARCHAR(100);
SET @MIGRATION_TABLE_1= convert(varchar(25), getdate(),121);
SET @MIGRATION_TABLE_1=REPLACE(@MIGRATION_TABLE_1,' ','_');
SET @MIGRATION_TABLE_1=STUFF(@MIGRATION_TABLE_1,14,1,'h')
SET @MIGRATION_TABLE_1=STUFF(@MIGRATION_TABLE_1,17,1,'m')
SET @MIGRATION_TABLE_1=STUFF(@MIGRATION_TABLE_1,20,1,'s')
SET @MIGRATION_TABLE_1='MY_TABLE_'+@MIGRATION_TABLE_1;
```

The `STUFF` function calls are for replacing the , `:` and `.` in the default date format

`2019-03-25 08:45:32.687` to

`2019-03-25_08h45m32s687`

At this stage, you can display the content of the variable `@MIGRATION_TABLE_1` with

```
SELECT @MIGRATION_TABLE_1 AS VARCHAR;
```

Then, you have to use the variable name into an `EXEC` statement as everything has to be dynamic, for example :

```
EXEC('CREATE TABLE ' + @tablename + ' REST OF YOUR ARGUMENTS);
```